# Hexagon is less perimeter-efficient than a square?

Tags: geometry

I am confused why a hexagon seems to have a less efficient perimeter than a square. For example, given a circle and square of the same area, the circle will have a smaller perimeter.

For a hexagon, however, of side **s** and a square of side **q** both having the same area the relationship between s and q is $$q=\sqrt{\frac{3 \sqrt{3}}{2}} s\approx 1.456 s$$

Which means the perimeter of the square is 5.824s, i.e., less than the perimeter of the hexagon 6s. Is my calculation wrong or are hexagons less perimeter-efficient than squares? Wait a minute, bees can't be wrong!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get $\sqrt{\frac {3\sqrt 3}2}\approx 1.612$ from [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%283%2asqrt%283%29/2%29) so the perimeter of the square is about $6.448$, greater than the hexagon

Comment: Right, I was miscalculating the inner square root of 3 as the square root of 2.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose a regular hexagon has area $1$.  Then 
$$
1 = \frac{3\sqrt3}{2}s \implies s^2 = \frac{2}{3\sqrt 3} \implies p_H= 6 \sqrt{\frac{2}{3\sqrt 3}} \approx 3.722
$$
On the other hand, the square of area $1$ will have a side of length $1$, so that $p_S = 4$.  So, the perimeter of a hexagon is smaller than that of a square with the same area.  It seems that a hexagon is indeed more "perimeter-efficient".  For a hexagon and square of the same area, we will have
$$
p_H/p_S = \frac{3}{2} \sqrt{\frac{2}{3\sqrt 3}} \approx 93\%
$$

Answer (score 0):

The perimeter of  the square of area $1$ is $4$.

Take a hexagon of perimeter $4$. Then the sides are $\frac{4}{6}$. The area is
$$6 \left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^2 \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}.$$
This is $\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}$, definitely bigger than $1$.